# How to add google maps script to wordpress post?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps

I want to insert a piece of javascript to Wordpress post page, What is the best way to insert this code?

```
<style type="text/css">
    #map-canvas { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=api">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
            mapOptions);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

How can I HARDCODE THIS? how to insert div elements correctly to my post?

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be using [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) and [wp_register_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) functions to include the javascript files using the [wp_enqueue_Scripts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) hook

I would do the following:

in your **functions.php**:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_scripts' );
function add_my_scripts(){
    // register the scripts
    wp_register_script( 'gmap', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=api' );
    wp_register_script( 'theme-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/my-script.js', array('gmap') );

    // enqueue only if needed
    if( is_page('your-map-page') ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('gmap');
        wp_enqueue_script('theme-js');
    }
}
// register a shortcode to use like [google-map]
add_shortcode('google-map', 'google_map_func');
function google_map_func() {
    return '<div id="map-canvas" style="height: 100%; margin: 0;padding: 0;"></div>';
}
```

In your **my-script.js**:

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions);
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm using visual composer and don't want to make any changes to function.php, is there any workaround?

Comment: I doesnt have features that i need. I want to have 14custom pins on map, conposer allows only 1, and i have no ability to add api key, for more maps.

Comment: Well I told you the "WordPress way" to do it, as far as me there is no other way to do it right.